# ggplot missing all axis labels

Tags: r, ggplot2

For some reason this ggplot refuses to include any information for the axes. I would love to have an x axis title and breaks, but it's not working. Even though it ignores the `name` and `breaks` arguments when they're included, it does respond to `limits`.

I assume this is just some syntax error I'm making. I hope this can be solved without a reprex, but I'm working on getting that ready.

I'm including the plot made with the full script, and the code below it is the minimum to produce the error.
[image]

```
Raman <- ggplot(data = spectra_raw, aes(x = raman.shift, y = counts, color = Sample, group = spectra)) + 
  facet_wrap(~for_facet, scales = "free_y", ncol = 1) + 
  geom_line() + 
  scale_x_continuous(name = "Raman shift (cm -1)", limits = c(60, 1500))
Raman
```

```
> str(spectra_raw)
'data.frame':   22945 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ raman.shift: num  50.7 52 53.2 54.5 55.7 ...
 $ counts     : num  0 5.28 18.39 14.45 3.43 ...
 $ spectra    : chr  "Anatase" "Anatase" "Anatase" "Anatase" ...
 $ Sample     : chr  "Anatase" "Anatase" "Anatase" "Anatase" ...
 $ for_facet  : chr  "Reference Minerals" "Reference Minerals" "Reference Minerals" "Reference Minerals" ...
```

Comment: Did you make any adjustments to your default ggplot theme before this? Does the problem persist if you restart R? Maybe try `theme_set(theme_grey())`

Comment: @MrFlick I haven't changed anything to the default ggplot theme (that I know of?), the restart did nothing, and `theme_grey` didn't change the outcome.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem by making a data.frame with the values from your `str()` output and then using your plotting code; the axis labels and titles appear just fine so I can't imagine this being a syntax error. Weird question, but have you loaded ggtern in the R session where you make this plot? (If so, does a clean session without ever loading ggtern make the plot you want?).

Comment: I tried your code on another dataset and it works perfectly. There must be a change in the settings, otherwise you would have "raman.shift" as x label and "counts" as y label. Maybe re-install the ggplot2 package and try again?

Comment: @teunbrand Now it works perfectly if I don't have ggtern in the session - thank you! Any idea why this was overriding the ggplot defaults?

Comment: The ggtern package overrides several functions of the ggplot2 package to make the ternary plots, including essential ones like `aes()` and `theme()`. This really isn't the best programming practise in general, as this means that ggtern should follow the exact footsteps of ggplot2 development (which I don't imagine they do). But it is especially annoying when it causes weird side-effects such as these.